# Autocomplete funciona, meu problema é com os seletores jquery para campos dinâmicos

Tags: jquery

Peço a ajuda de alguém para me ensinar a fazer seletor Jquery funcionar com campos dinâmicos... Eu crio linhas no formulário a partir de um evento que define a quantidade de linhas a nota terá... a partir dai ele cria as linhas e o primeiro campo tem um autocomplete, que funciona! Os demais campos utilizam a informação do auto complete para preencher o restante das informações... Eu crio um looping para criar as linhas e defino as requisições ajax no javascript ... O problema acontece quando seleciono o autocomplete nas linhas adicionais... Por causa do seletor dos campos terem o nome igual... Ou ele muda as informações em todas as demais linhas de uma vez, ou se eu usar eq(z) como seletor ele só altera as demais informações na ultima linha... Já tentei de tudo que se possa imaginar... Preciso de ajuda... O problema é como definir o seletor dos campos dinâmicos, pois tem a mesma class e name...

```html
<div id="origem">

<div class="row">
<div class="col col-md-3">
<div class="input-group">

<input type="text" class="auto form-control" id="autoprod" name="prod[0]" placeholder="Produto...">

<input type="hidden" id="prodid" name="prodid[0]" value="0">

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){

var i = 0;

$('#autoprod').eq(i).autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {

$.ajax({
url:'<?php echo base_url().'Compras/prodList'; ?>',
type: 'post',
dataType: 'json',
data: {
search: request.term
},
success: function(data){
response(data);
}

});
},
select: function(event, ui){
$('#autoprod').eq(i).val(ui.item.label);
$('#prodid').val(ui.item.value);
$('#marca').val(ui.item.marc);
$('#unit').val(ui.item.uni);

return false;
}

});
});





</script>


</div>


</div>
<div class="col col-md-2">
<div class="input-group">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="marca" name="marca[0]" placeholder="Marca..." readonly>

</div>
</div>


<div class="col">
<div class="input-group">



<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="unit" name="unit[0]" placeholder="Unidade..." readonly>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lugar" name="unit2[0]" placeholder="Unidade..." readonly>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#autoprod").on('blur', function() {
var txt = $('#unit').val();

var jtxt = {
'valor1': txt
};

$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo base_url()."Compras/ajax"; ?>',
type: 'post',
data: jtxt,
dataType:'json',
success:function(resultado) {

$("#lugar").val(resultado[0].nome_unit);


},
error:function(){
alert("Este produto não existe... Preencha corretamente o formulário!");

},



});

});
});




</script>




</div>
</div>



<div class="col">
<div class="input-group">

<input type="text" class="form-control money2" maxlength="15" id="valorunit" name="valorunit[0]" pattern="^$?[0-9]+(,[0-9]{3})*(.[0-9]{2})?$" onkeydown="function(money2);" placeholder="Preço Unit. (R$)" required>

</div>


</div>
<div class="col">
<div class="input-group">

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="quant" name="quant[0]" min="1" max="999" placeholder="Quantidade" onblur="mult()" value="1" required>

</div>


</div>
<div class="col">
<div class="input-group">

<input type="text" class="form-control money2" maxlength="15" id="totalp" name="totalp[0]" onfocus="function(money2);" placeholder="Total (R$)" required readonly>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function id(valor_campo) {
return document.getElementById(valor_campo);
}

function getValor(valor_campo) {
var valor = document.getElementById(valor_campo).value.replace('.','');
valor = valor.replace(',','.');
return parseFloat(valor);
}

function mult() {
var total = getValor('valorunit') * getValor('quant');
id('totalp').value = total.toFixed(2);
}

</script>

</div>
</div>
</br>
</div>

<div id="destino">

</div>
Restante de formulário:

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#qt").on('blur', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
document.getElementById("qt").readOnly = true;
document.getElementById("destino").innerHTML="";

var qtr = $("#qt").val();

var i = 1;

while (i < qtr) {

var z = i - 1;


var t = '<div class="row">\<div class="col-3">\<div class="input-group">\<input type="text" class="autot form-control" name="prod[0]" placeholder="Produto...">\<input type="hidden" class="idr" name="prodid[0]" value="0">\</div></div>\<div class="col-2">\<div class="input-group">\<input type="text" class="nname form-control" name="marca[0]" placeholder="Marca..." readonly>\</div></div>\<div class="col">\<div class="input-group">\<input type="hidden" class="uunit form-control" name="unit[0]" placeholder="Unidade..." readonly>\<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lugar" name="unit2[0]" placeholder="Unidade..." readonly>\</div></div>\<div class="col">\<div class="input-group">\<input type="text" class="form-control money2" maxlength="15" id="valorunit" name="valorunit[0]" pattern="^$?[0-9]+(,[0-9]{3})*(.[0-9]{2})?$" onkeydown="function(money2);" placeholder="Preço Unit. (R$)" required>\</div></div>\<div class="col">\<div class="input-group">\<input type="number" class="form-control" id="quant" name="quant[0]" min="1" max="999" placeholder="Quantidade" onblur="mult()" value="1" required>\</div></div>\<div class="col">\<div class="input-group">\<input type="text" class="form-control money2" maxlength="15" id="totalp" name="totalp[0]" onfocus="function(money2);" placeholder="Total (R$)" required readonly>\</div></div></div></br>';

$("#destino").append(t);


$('.autot').autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {

$.ajax({
url:'<?php echo base_url().'Compras/prodList'; ?>',
type: 'post',
dataType: 'json',
data: {
search: request.term
},
success: function(data){
response(data);
}

});
},
select: function(event, ui){


$(this).val(ui.item.label);

$('.idr').val(ui.item.value);

$('.nname').val(ui.item.marc);

$('.uunit').val(ui.item.uni);


return false;

}

});



i = i + 1;


}


});

});


</script>

</br></br>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta buscar os elementos que estão na mesma div `.row`. Use `.closest(".row")` para selecionar a linha inteira e o `.find()` para encontrar o elemento  desejado.

Por exemplo, para selecionar e alterar o valor do elemento `.idr` da linha, você usa:

```
$(this).closest(".row").find(".idr").val(ui.item.value);
```

Comment: Sam; muito obrigado pela resposta, mas o problema não é no autocomplete em si... O problema está depois do autocomplete... São os campos que depois de selecionado o autocomplete, serão preenchidos... No caso as class '.idr', 'nname', e 'uunit'... Se puder me explicar como selecioná-los, somente o da linha inserida, uma de cada vez... Agradeço desde já! Obrigado!

Comment: Sam; VALEU AMIGO! Era isso... Já tinha tentado find(), next(), parent()... A palavrinha mágica foi o closest()! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Sam; Desculpe incomodar de novo, mas utilizei a mesma lógica para chamar os próximos elementos da mesma linha e não deu certo...

Comment: Como assim "os proximos elementos"?

Comment: Então, os próximos inputs da linha... Como chamá-los? Em outros scripts eu vou precisar trabalhar com os próximos campos, como na figura acima, Unit., R$, Quant. R$ Total... Usei o closest() para definir apenas os campos da mesma linha, e não funcionou, se não usar funciona, mas altera todos os inputs das outras linhas... Como seleciono um input aleatório de uma linha criada dinamicamente?

Comment: Vai depender de qual linha vc quer pegar.

Comment: Acho que não tô entendendo direito. Vc disse que havia funcionado o .closest().

Comment: Sam, me ajuda.... :)

Comment: O problema é no `$(this).closest('.row').find('.llugar').val(res);`... esse `$(this)` dentro da function do success não aponta mais para o .autot.

Comment: Após a linha `$(document).on("blur", ".autot", function(){` vc vai colocar: `var $this = $(this);`... agora vc usa `$this` em vez de `$(this)` no .closest, isso dentro do success, assim: `$this.closest('.row').find('.llugar').val(res);`

Comment: Sam, você é o cara! Valeu de novo... Você tem algum curso de javascript mais avançado que vc ensine? Ou indica algum?

Comment: Cara, procura no Google que tem mt material bom por aí.